# Core-Plot: y-axis labels outside initially, but inside plot subsequently

Tags: positioning, core-plot, axis-labels

I'm using Core-Plot 0.9 and have a seemingly peculiar problem. I have an X-Y plot with labels on the y-axis. When the plot is initially displayed, the labels are correctly positioned on the tick marks (actually offset 1.0) to the left of the axis itself, which is correct.

Then, I select a new set of data to display using a UIPickerView to set the x-axis starting point and regenerate the plot. On this and all subsequent regenerations of the plot, the y-axis labels show up inside the plot (to the right of the axis) and not on the tick marks (actually shifted upwards a bit.

I have created what I think is enough room on the left hand side of the plot to contain the y-axis labels. In particular, I have code as follows:

```
graph.paddingLeft = 0.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 25.0;

y.labelOffset = 1.0f;
y.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentLeft;
```

Here is the correct representation of the y-axis labels on initial loading.

[image]
<sub>(source: [msyapps.com](http://www.msyapps.com/gifs/Correct.png))</sub>

Here is the incorrect representation of the y-axis labels after scrolling the picker view on the left and regenerating the plot.

[image]
<sub>(source: [msyapps.com](http://www.msyapps.com/gifs/Incorrect.png))</sub>

Comment: Perhaps I am not asking the questions in an intelligible way. I wish I could show images of the situation, because a picture or two may be better than my English.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/fee73a040defce9b?pli=1&fb_source=message This might sound useful!

Comment: Siddharthan, Thanks. That discussion and the included images are similar to what I am experiencing. The difference it seems is that my labels end up in the incorrect position except when I very carefully move the scroll wheel up and down just a little bit but not enough to move to a different row. In this odd way, I can get the labels to show in the proper location but this is just a kluge. I can't understand the remedy suggested and from the discussion, it seems that it doesn't work either and requires modifying the core-plot code, something that I don't think I should attempt.

Comment: I've been playing with graph.paddingLeft and graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft. All that happens is that the rightward shift is or seems to be exactly the amount of graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft. The greater the padding, the greater the rightward shift.

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the `tickDirection` property? That's what controls which side the labels are on.

Comment: Eric, At your suggestion, I added a tickDirection specification CPTSignNegative, which I believe is the default. As I say, the first instance of creating the plot shows the labels and ticks in their intended left location. The subsequent instances show the ticks properly, but the labels mysteriously appear inside the plot, i.e., to the right of the y-axis and shifted a bit upward. Adding the tickDirection doesn't solve the mystery.

Comment: Eric, I just tried all three variations for tickDirection: CPTSignNegative, CPTSignNone, and CPTSignPositive. Both Negative and None resulted in the labels showing on the left as desired, but on subsequent plots the same problem arose. Positive put the label on the right inside the plot both initially and subsequently, albeit the subsequent instances all showed shifts further to the right. Perhaps there is a bug in the linkage between labels and tick marks.

Comment: I've been trying other potential fixes or tests to see what might be causing the misbehavior upon regeneration. For example, I forced the plotSpace.yRange to minimum and maximum values rather than letting the changing dataset determine the plotSpace.yRange. Still the problem persists. I've played around endlessly with the graph.paddingLeft and graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft parameters to no avail. I wonder if there is some way to force the axis and there labels to stay in one place on the graph irrespective of what happens to the plot. In other words, can the axis be put in a separate bucket?

Comment: Try something like this: `y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];`

Comment: Yup, tried that too, Eric. My code includes y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constrainWithUpperOffset:285]; to create a little separation between the x- and y-axes for a better appearance, but neither your idea nor mine have any affect upon the display. Strange as it may seem, I think the problem lies within the UIPickerView because if I am really careful in moving the scroll wheel back and forth over a particular selection without moving either up or down to a new row, the display can be made to render properly. Very, very odd. I wonder if it would help to post all my code?

Comment: Eric, Might this problem be corrected by update 927b253cb2cc? If so, I'd sure like to get the changes needed because this bug is preventing me from submitting my app to Apple and I have several more apps with virtually identical code in the works. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible. Why don't you pull the latest code with Mercurial and give it a try?

Comment: Eric, Apparently I'm not savvy enough to use Mercurial. I downloaded it, but will have to find some help to learn how to use it to get the update. Heck, I can't even find it on my computer. I wonder if I could do the update manually from the code that is posted. If I try that, what do the colors on various lines mean? I appreciate your responses and know that in time the solution will appear even if by magic. ;-)

Comment: The Core Plot wiki has some links to Mercurial info at http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingMercurial. The source code checkout page at http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/checkout gives you the Mercurial command needed to create your local repository. If you're looking at the Google Code diff pages, the red sections on the left are the previous revision and the green areas on the right are the current one. The text highlighted within those sections is what actually changed.

Comment: Eric, I hard-coded the changes in /core-plot/framework/source/ but still there is no change in the app. I've never given up before, but this may be the first time. I'm well-burnt toast. Bummer.

Comment: Can you post your Core Plot-related code beyond the snippet in the original question? I want to make sure this isn't a Core Plot bug. :-)

Comment: Yes, Eric, I'd be happy to. Is it okay to post it here or should I start as if it is a new question. BTW, I've found that the problem might be in the padding. For example, I can get the upward shifting to stop by setting graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 0.0; rather than say = 5.0. Also, the labels stay where they belong provided I set graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 0.0; which seems contrary to so much of what is said when someone reports that the y-axis goes missing. Now I have to mess with the parameters of the x-axis to get the rest of the plot to look right. Hope this clue helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workable solution, but it violates the commonly recommended action for displaying the y-axis. The annotations in the code snippet below indicates where I think I deviated from conventions and where I think I have added a unique solution for fixing the y-axis in place on subsequent redrawing of plot.

```
#pragma mark - Choose returns to chart
- (IBAction)returnsToChart:(int)startPt andInteger:(int)endPt; { 
    contentArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
    dataContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
    int xPosition = 0;
    for (int i=startPt; i<endPt+1; ++i) {
        [dataContent addObject:[returnsAll objectAtIndex:i]];
        id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:xPosition];
        id y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[returnsAll objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]];
        if ([[returnsAll objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [contentArray1 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", @"", @"y", nil]];
        }
        else {
            [contentArray1 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]]; }
        xPosition = xPosition + 1;
    }

    dataForPlot = contentArray1;

    quarterlyReturnView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 8.0f, 320.0f, 240.0f);    

    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];    
    quarterlyReturnView.hostedGraph = graph;

    //paddingLeft leaves room for y-axis labels
    //paddingBottom must be set at zero otherwise and the space that must be added in order for the bottom-most label text to show will be handled by extending the length of the y-axis downward by a little bit
    graph.paddingLeft = 8.0;
    graph.paddingTop = 5.0;
    graph.paddingRight = 5.0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 0.0;

    //convention says that paddingLeft should be some number greater than zero
    //convention says that paddingBottom should be some number greater than zero, but if greater than zero, then each subsequent redrawing of plot results in a label shift upwards by the non-zero amount
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 0.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 5.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 5.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 0.0;

    // Setup plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    //this is where the magic happens...
    //I tweaked the percentage adjustments for the location as a function of the number of data points along the x-axis that had to be plotted
    //I settled on 8% plus and minus to provide room for the y-axis labels
    //this percentage is expressed as -0.08*(datacontent.count-1.0) and 1.08*(datacontent.count-1.0)
    //in other words, I put 8% on the left-hand side of the x-axis and made the whole x-axis 108% of the number of data points

    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-0.08 * (dataContent.count-1.0)) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.08 * (dataContent.count-1.0))];

    //Text styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleTextStyle = [CPTTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica";
    axisTitleTextStyle.fontSize = 9.0;

    //Grid styles
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5f;

    //Axis styles
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

    float maxNum = -100.0;
    float minNum = 100.0;
    float testMaxNum = 0.0;
    float testMinNum = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<[dataContent count]; ++i) {
        if ([[dataContent objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]) { }
        else {
            testMaxNum = [[dataContent objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
            if (maxNum < testMaxNum) { maxNum = testMaxNum; }
            testMinNum = [[dataContent objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
            if (minNum > testMinNum) { minNum = testMinNum; } }
    }
    int maxInt = (maxNum + 1.0) / 1.0;
    float yMax = 1.0 * maxInt;
    int minInt = (minNum - 1.0) / 1.0;
    float yMin = 1.0 * minInt;

    //here is where the y-axis is stretched a bit to allow the labels to show unclipped
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMin-0.2) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMax-yMin+0.2)];

    // Axes (x is horizontal; y is vertical)
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelOffset = 1.0f;
    x.labelTextStyle = nil;
    x.majorTickLength = 5.0f;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"16");
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    x.minorTickLength = 0.0f;
    x.tickDirection =CPTSignNone;
    x.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(dataContent.count-1.0)];

    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    y.labelFormatter = formatter;
    y.labelOffset = 2.0f;
    y.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentLeft;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTitleTextStyle;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;    
    y.majorTickLength = 3.0f;    
    y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"2");
    y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    //y.gridLinesRange is needed because the x-axis has been stretched 8% as described above
    y.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(dataContent.count-1)];
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
    y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");

    // Create plot area
    CPTScatterPlot *boundLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    lineStyle.miterLimit = 1.0f;
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    boundLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:boundLinePlot];
    [boundLinePlot reloadData];
}
```